# For which languages should I use SET NAMES in mysql?

Tags: mysql, localization

In order to get Hebrew text into the DB, I have to use SET NAMES 'hebrew'. For which other languages should I do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; you should *not* `SET NAMES 'hebrew'`. This will lock you in to using a Hebrew-specific character set, making it impossible to store text in other non-Roman scripts.

Use `SET NAMES 'utf8'` to set MySQL to store text as Unicode. Always.

Comment: If the client uses an encoding that is incompatible with utf8 that would most probably kill all texts, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Best is to do it always, that's the only way to be sure your encoding is 100% correctly transmitted between Database and Client.

Always use `SET NAMES` with the character set your client is running on.

For example if your client code got strings and expects strings in utf-8 set it to utf-8, if you're running on latin1 set it to latin1.

Effectively it tells the Database what characterset you want to communicate in, what character set your data uses and what character set you want for the result.